# spock unit test loops in then clause

Tags: testing, loops, spock, clause

I have a test with loops in the then clause:

```
result.each {
  it.name.contains("foo")
  it.entity.subEntity == "bar"
}

for (String obj : result2) {
  obj.name.contains("foo")
  obj.entity.subEntity == "bar"
}
```

Newly I recognized that the loops are not really tested. No matter whether I have foo or bar or anything else, the test is always green :)
I found out, that loops have to be tested differently, e.g. with 'every'? But just changing the 'each' to 'every' throws exception:

```
result.every {
  it.name.contains("foo")
  it.entity.subEntity == "bar"
}

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Spec expression: 1: expecting '}', found '==' @ line 1, column 61.
   s("foo") it.entity.rootEntity == "bar" }
```

How should I correctly use loops in my test? I am using spock 0.7-groovy-2.0

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Either use explicit assert statements:

```
result.each {
    assert it.name.contains("foo")
    assert it.entity.subEntity == "bar"
}
```

Or a single boolean expression within `every`:

```
result.every {
    it.name.contains("foo") && it.entity.subEntity == "bar"
}
```

Comment: Warning! First approach will generate more readable failure messages but will be evaluated to `false` (and operation fail) in case of `result` is empty collection!

Comment: Additional warning: second method may run into [presently unresolved bug](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/253) if the closure you pass to `every` is multiple lines.